How to delete all text after the 8th comma with Notepad++?
I have a TXT file with a lot of rows.
Each row has several pieces of data, separated by commas.
Is there a way of deleting all the data after, say, the 8th comma?

Use Search/Replace (Ctrl+H) and enable "regular expressions".
If you want to keep the 8th comma

Find what: ^(?:[^,]*,){8}\K.*$
Replace with:   (leave empty)

If you want to remove the 8th comma

Find what: ^(?:[^,]*,){7}[^,]+\K.*$
Replace with:   (leave empty)

Elements of construction:

^: start of the line
$: end of the line
[^,]*: any text, but not a comma
,: a comma
(?:): non-capturing group
{8}: repeat 8 times
\K: reset the match, i.e. everything before will not be selected
.*: everything that remains

